# Unable to run this code as an Macro

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

**Any idea why I'm unable to run this code as an Macro?**

```
Sub PivotFilter()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim PI As PivotItem

With Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("OrgUnit Code:")
    .ClearAllFilters

    'Refreshing pivot table seems to remove the "set visible property" error
    Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable2").RefreshTable

For Each PI In .PivotItems
    PI.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("b:b"), PI.Name) > 0
Next PI

End With

    Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable1").RefreshTable

End Sub
```

Any idea what the reason for this may be?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: @litelite I dont get any error - I'm simply not able to run the code. When I push the green button "Run" I get a box where I can choose a Macro but the are no macros I can select.

Comment: Put your cursor between `Sub ... End Sub` and run?

Comment: @Brian I'm doing that - but I get a Macros dialog box where I can choose a Macro but the are no macros I can select.

Comment: @pnuts it will not solve his problem, but it do will solve the problem he will have when he will be able to run the macro.

Comment: Did you add your code to a form, or to a Module?

Comment: @pnuts can you please look at this issue/question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38970726/how-to-run-a-macro-automaticly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making it public

```
Public Sub PivotFilter()
     '...
End Sub
```

Excel sometimes can't/don't want to run private subs when running with the play button or pressing f5

Comment: If it is a code module (not object or class) then `public` is the default scope.

Comment: @litelite can you please look at this issue/question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38970726/how-to-run-a-macro-automaticly?noredirect=1#comment65296705_38970726)